# AS3: Setting the movieclip's frame position as a variable

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created a slider, and want to link the slider knob's X value to the frame position in a movieclip. It will work a little like a timeline bar. For example if the slider knob's x position is 12, it will change myMC to frame 12 etc..

Also, I don't understand how to create a variable for the myMC's frame position. But this is what I have so far.

```
var sliderValue:uint = mySlider.sliderKnob.x / 3;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    sliderValue = mySlider.sliderKnob.x / 3;

    sliderValue.Number = myMC.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to see some context for this code, but it looks like what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    sliderValue = mySlider.sliderKnob.x / 3;
    myMC.gotoAndStop(sliderValue);
}
```

I have no idea if this is actually correct as `3` appears to be an arbitrary number. In any case, the way you "set" the frame of a `MovieClip` is by calling the `gotoAndStop` function and passing either a frame number (as above), or a valid frame label.

You'll definitely want to do some error checking on `sliderValue` to make sure that it falls somewhere between `1` and `myMC.totalFrames`.

Comment: thank you so much, this 100% solves it. Sorry, i'm still really new to flash